# Does "This blows!" (it's bad) derive from "This sucks!"?

Tags: etymology, slang, offensive-language

The origin of [**blow** = suck, be bad/unpleasant](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22this%20blows%20i%20said%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) recently came up in comments to [this ELL question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/124801/2637).

I'd always assumed it was a standard slang "meaning reversal" from *suck*. But a few minutes on Google failed to confirm this for me, and in that ELL link, Feral Oink credibly suggests it's from [blow chunks](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blow_chunks) *- to be very bad, inadequate, unpleasant, or miserable; to thoroughly suck*.

Does anyone know when and why the usage arose?

Comment: I've never heard the expression. Is this UK slang?

Comment: I am very sure it is a synonym to this sucks

Comment: @TrevorD: I would have guessed it started in the US myself, but that's probably because I *assume* it's related to *sucks* (which I also *think* is of US origin). Of the two authors in my first link, I can't establish the nationality of the first (Ross Stein), but the second ([Ernest Cline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Cline)) is definitely American.

Comment: No evidence I know of, but they are so synonymous I always assumed they both derived from the same source (a reference to fellatio). I don't really care to dive into Google to investigate further, for reasons that ought to be obvious. :-)

Comment: @T.E.D.: To be honest, I'm far from convinced "This sucks!" has its roots in fellatio anyway. I'm just assuming the answer to *that* question will be peripherally (but definitively) addressed here too.

Comment: ...I have this vague idea *"This sucks!"* is related to *"Aw, shucks!"*, *"Ah, shoot!"*, etc. (which I guess are euphemisms for *"Shit!"*).

Comment: Interesting, I'd always though it came from "this sucks balls" which is close though not quite fellatio.

Comment: @terdon You could be right, but frankly I never heard your version until the last couple of decades, whereas I've heard "sucks" by itself since at least the 70's. So IMO your version is just a recent elaboration for emphasis. That is often done. Typical elaborations (which I've heard at least as far back as the early 80's) featured a description of the phallus involved in the sucking. (Sorry, but I didn't bring this topic up...)

Comment: This question reminds me of the riddle, "Why does the wind always blow from south to north in [Kansas](http://www.smart-traveler.info/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderpictures/map_of_kansas.gif)?" (Answer: "Because Oklahoma blows and Nebraska sucks!") Of course, you can adapt this riddle to your local geography (e.g., "Why does the wind always blow from west to east in Saskatchewan?")

Comment: @T.E.D. you are very likely right, that was just my assumption and I have no data to back it up with. I came across [this](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=583268) very interesting thread that gives a nice list of examples which I am pretty sure predate the testicular connections of the phrase.

Comment: @J.R. - I know that joke with Oklahoma in the middle and KS and TX on the sides (as a resident of Oklahoma, that makes sense). I think this is actually a very important point, as that joke makes no sense unless you can count on an audience that knows both meanings for both words. So you could probably trace the origins of both terms to the states that feature in the middle of versions of this joke.

Comment: Bart Simpson on occasion has said "I didn't think it was physically possible, but this both sucks and blows."

Comment: @Cyberherbalist: I thought it was interesting (obviously, or I wouldn't have asked). What baffles me is that a couple of people thought it was bad enough to actually *downvote* - which I usually take to mean they think the answer is obvious, making the question trivial. *Faute de mieux*, I've just accepted Barrie's post, but it doesn't really answer the question for me (actually, by implying that ***sucks** derives from **blow*** rather than the other way around, it makes the whole thing even more mysterious). Hardly "trivial", imho.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  I've been downvoted for seemingly no reason before.  Comes with the territory I guess.  No accounting for taste.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist: It's not that I "worry" in the sense of feeling rejected or hard done by because someone doesn't like my question. It's more about the fact that I'm curious/nosey, and it frustrates me when people do things for reasons I don't understand. I suppose you're right though. That attitude has served me well analysing "unexpected behaviour" in computer systems over the years, where there's nearly always a rational explanation that can in principle be teased out if you put the effort in. But unexpected behaviour from *unknown **people*** is a whole nother ball game.

Comment: Oh, yes. People.  Keeping users out of systems is very important!  They mess everything up.  Just this morning I had a user put in a bug report that she couldn't bring up a given system user using that user's name.  And neither could I, when I tried to replicate.  I puzzled over it for awhile and then noticed that they had exchanged the first and last names!  Once this was fixed the problem of course went away.  Yes, sir, letting users use systems can be downright dangerous!  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OED’s definition 15f of *suck* is ‘To be contemptible or disgusting’. The earliest citation is from 1971. The OED relates it to the noun *suck*, Canadian slang for ‘A worthless or contemptible person’. This in turn may or may not (the OED doesn’t say) have something to do with ‘sucks’ used, particularly by children, as an expression of contempt.

The OED also has an entry for *blow* as a draft addition in 2009, where the definition is given as ‘To be contemptible, tiresome, or disagreeable’. It is described as North American slang, and there is a cross reference to *suck*. The earliest citation predates the earliest citation for derogatory *suck* by 11 years.

Comment: Do we suppose that Canadian usage derived from (US?) *sucker?* Or maybe it's just a euphemistic variant on *fuck* (as in *"You useless fuck!"*

Comment: I suspect any resemblance in the sound is incidental. The use of _sucker_ to mean, in the OED’s definition, ‘A greenhorn, simpleton’ seems to be related to the use of the term to describe a young mammal before it is weaned.

Comment: A post on [this](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=583268) thread quotes the OED as giving examples of _suck_ in a negative context from 1913. I don't have access to an OED at the moment, does yours not confirm this?

Comment: It does. It's where I got the fourth sentence of my answer from.

Comment: +1ing this just for finding the most relevant OED reference and making it available to us meer peons.

Answer (score 6):

Did some research on this based on information in the comments.

There appear to be two schools of thought on the etymology of the adjective "sucks".

The first is that it comes from relative innocuous roots (one possible example: the phrase "suck eggs", which can be found in the works of Mark Twain).

The second is that the roots of the term are in its older meaning of fellatio. For example, [Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=suck&allowed_in_frame=0)'s entry says:

> Meaning "do fellatio" is first recorded 1928. Slang sense of "be
>   contemptible" first attested 1971 (the underlying notion is of
>   fellatio).

This better matches the traditional intent of the word (as a longtime user from at least the mid-70's), as well as the variants often heard in the wild (which invariably are elaborations on the theme of oral sex). Still, it would be tough to say which, if indeed either, interpretation is correct.

As for "blows", I couldn't find much. Supposedly it originates from the USA in the 80's. I did happen to be a big user of the word myself, as a teenager in the early 80's. I know my peers (in the middle of the USA) used it as a nearly exact synonym for "sucks", for those occasions when that word had been used enough that its impact may not quite be as hefty as desired. Really its best to alternate.

As a near synonym, it had the same vulgar connotations to us as "sucks". However, it is true that one could tack on "monkey chunks" to transform it into a slightly different vulgarity (making it a bit more versatile, and thus preferred by some of my fellow connoisseurs of angst). I can't for sure say if the "monkey chunks" predated the lone sense of "blows", so exactly which of the two bodily actions it was originally intended to imply can perhaps only be discerned through further research. Possibly a good dissertation for someone in the offing here.

Comment: I'm very sorry that for the second half (the actual germane portion) I was forced to rely on myself as a primary source, rather than research. If anyone can find a good reference that realistically predates my own experience with it, please speak up.

Answer (score 5):

I have a **1983** script from an Off-Broadway revue which includes the line "our foreign policy blows dead rats."

This suggests that *blows* and *sucks* are parallel derivations (in their sexual meaning).

This is not related to "blow chunks", which refers to vomiting.

Comment: Well, again I can vouch for personally having used "blows" as a synonym for "sucks" earlier than '83. So IMHO this find isn't early enough to be enlightening on the matter. Look at scripts for movies aimed at teenagers, and I bet you'll find several earlier references.

Comment: Is this a variation of "That blows chunks"? (Which may or may not be the source for "That blows".)

Comment: I used it earlier myself (I was in that revue), but I figure citations are better than anecdotes.

Comment: I disagree, but then, my sadly downvoted response makes this clear enough, I guess.  On another hand, where's *your* documentation?  I could say I had a document in my position to support *my* answer, then @FumbleFingers would have to take his downvote back.  So scan the doc and post it on Flickr or something.  :-)

Comment: @Cyberherbalist: While there may be cases as you describe, the meaning of this particular instance is not ambiguous; so there's really nothing to disagree with here. The name of the revue was "Off the Wall (or Did I Put My Foot in Your Mouth?)"

Answer (score 1):

I have always understood "this blows" to be a shortened form of "this blows chunks", or, in other words, "this causes me to vomit".  That's what those chunks are -- your stomach contents on display.  Although nobody actually vomits.

It has the same general meaning of "this sucks", that is, something which is bad or unacceptable.  But "sucks" in this usage has reference to certain obscene conduct and not to the opposite of vomiting.

Comment: You'll probably think I'm being a bit harsh, but -1 for simply repeating a possible origin that I've already mentioned in the question, *with no supporting references*. (I'll go and find one of your earlier answers that I can upvote, to balance things out! :)

Comment: You're being harsh?  Oh, @FumbleFingers don't worry about it. What about the other downvoter, then?  On the other hand, my introductory phrase "I have always understood..." clearly signifies that this is my opinion, based upon my 60 years of speaking this incredibly fascinating language.  I thought I got extra credit for finding references to support my assertions, but to this point I wasn't aware my opinion needed supporting documentation.  If I were to say, "I think you are a very nice person", would you expect proof?  :-)