# Offensive phrase: what does "**ck my brains out" mean?

Tags: meaning, slang, offensive-language

Does this expression have to do with actual sex intercourse?

Or it is mostly used to describe a situation of some conflicts over little petty meaningless things, for example, preparing a work report?

"The boss totally **cked my brains out! I can't think anymore about that work report"

Comment: I've heard *mindfuck* and *mind fucking* used in that context, [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mindfuck) tells me that they are synonymous. I think Americans would say "My boss is screwing with my mind....."

Comment: Related [“Screwed” vs. “nailed”: why is the slang so different?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124801/screwed-vs-nailed-why-is-the-slang-so-different), the post should be visited if only because the accepted answer is so bloody brilliant.

Comment: As I've heard the phrase used, it means that very vigorous sexual intercourse occurred.  It may have a positive or negative connotation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can "f--- someone's brains out" be used to mean "steal someone's heart"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209600/can-f-someones-brains-out-be-used-to-mean-steal-someones-heart)

Answer (score 5):

In this case, as in surprisingly few others involving the word "f*ck," the phrase refers to sexual intercourse.

You can say "My boss totally f*cked me!" to mean, "My boss arranged things in such a way that my situation is now untenable."

If you said, "My boss totally f*cked my brains out!" however, I would suggest that you either go to a lawyer and file suit for sexual harassment or ask your boss for a raise and a promotion, depending on how pleased you were that this happened.

Comment: Partly due to the massive flexibility of the operative word here... http://grin.hu/funtxt/fido/en/fuck.html

Comment: wow, very good comment! hahaha, however i m not gonna file a lawsuit or ask for a raise.